# Fail to build extension due to ZEND_NUM_ARGS() macros

Tags: php, c, php-internals

I'm writing small php extension and have problem when building it.
The code:

```
PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION(pstat)
{
    int argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

on make got an error:

```
.... /ext/pstat/pstat.c:122:31: error: 'ht' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

ZEND_NUM_ARGS() is a macros in Zend_API.h

```
#define ZEND_NUM_ARGS()     (ht)
```

but what is 'ht'? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using `ZEND_NUM_ARGS()` here? This is the request initialisation function, and will not be receiving any user supplied arguments.

---

Typically but not always, `ht` is used to denote a hash table.

`ZEND_NUM_ARGS()` is usually used within a function defined with the `PHP_FUNCTION` macro, to get the number of arguments passed to an internal function from a PHP script.

---

If you trace back from the `PHP_FUNCTION` macro you'll end up seeing the following standard set of arguments used in an internal function definition.

```
#define INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS int ht, zval *return_value, zval **return_value_ptr, zval *this_ptr, int return_value_used TSRMLS_DC
```

As you can see, this definition includes `ht` as an int.

The arguments for `PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION` do not include `ht`.

```
#define INIT_FUNC_ARGS      int type, int module_number TSRMLS_DC
```

Comment: I want to save starttime of every request to php. I though PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION is a good idea.

Comment: Ok, so what do you need `ZEND_NUM_ARGS` for?

Comment: I though there are some arguments for request. Script name for example. Now I understand its a wrong place for my games.